# SQL - Time difference between 2 entries grouped by unique ID

Tags: sql, metabase

I have a table with multiple timestamp entries for different actions (let's call them Action 'A' and 'B') for distinct IDs, and I want to calculate the difference between them for each ID using SQL in Metabase.

To make things more complicated, I need to filter only the IDs that contain both action types, and there are sometimes repeated action names that are not always in the same order, so I need to find the MIN of Action 'A' and would want to get the next highest timestamp of Action 'B'.

For example, here is a dataset:

```
ID   | Action | Timestamp
----------------------------------------------
01   | A      | Thursday, June 6, 2019 6:25 AM <-First valid action for 'A' for ID 01
01   | B      | Thursday, June 6, 2019 6:30 AM <-First valid action for 'B' for ID 01
01   | A      | Thursday, June 6, 2019 6:35 AM
01   | B      | Thursday, June 6, 2019 6:40 AM
01   | A      | Thursday, June 6, 2019 6:45 AM
03   | B      | Monday, July 1, 2019 8:25 AM   <-SKIP, due to no Action 'A' present for ID 03
03   | B      | Monday, July 1, 2019 8:30 AM
10   | B      | Tuesday, July 2, 2019 9:40 AM
10   | A      | Tuesday, July 2, 2019 9:45 AM  <-First valid action for 'A' for ID 10
10   | A      | Tuesday, July 2, 2019 9:50 AM
10   | B      | Tuesday, July 2, 2019 9:55 AM  <-First valid action for 'B' for ID 10
```

The result I would want is to view only IDs that have BOTH Action 'A' and 'B' present (hint: if Action 'A' is present, there will always be an Action 'B', but sometimes there is only an action 'B'), and find the difference in timestamps from the first Action 'A' (that comes AFTER the earliest Action 'B'), and the next highest Action 'B'.

Desired result:

```
ID   | Difference
-----------------
01   | 5 min
10   | 10 min
```

So to summarize:

• How do I identify the first timestamp of Action 'B' following Action 'A'?

• How do I calculate the difference from that Action 'A' and the next highest Action 'B' to display in the same row in the results for each distinct ID?

• How do I view only IDs with both actions present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which SQL dialect you use, so I tried to write a query very close to standard SQL (for example, [SQL:2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2003)), but using [Postgres 8.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/index.html). For the character representation of date values, I used the format defined in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

```
create table T (
  ID char(2),
  Action char(1),
  "Timestamp" timestamp
);

insert into T values
  ('01', 'A', '2019-06-06T06:25'),
  ('01', 'B', '2019-06-06T06:30'),
  ('01', 'A', '2019-06-06T06:35'),
  ('01', 'B', '2019-06-06T06:40'),
  ('01', 'A', '2019-06-06T06:45'),
  ('03', 'B', '2019-07-01T08:25'),
  ('03', 'B', '2019-07-01T08:30'),
  ('10', 'B', '2019-07-02T09:40'),
  ('10', 'A', '2019-07-02T09:45'),
  ('10', 'A', '2019-07-02T09:50'),
  ('10', 'B', '2019-07-02T09:55');

select
  a.ID, extract(minute from (min(b."Timestamp") - a.min_ts)) as Difference
from (select
        t.ID, min(t."Timestamp") as min_ts
      from T as t
      where t.Action = 'A'
      group by t.ID, t.Action) as a
inner join T as b
  on a.ID = b.ID and b.Action = 'B' and a.min_ts < b."Timestamp"
group by a.ID, a.min_ts;
```

**Output:**

```
| id | difference |
+----+------------+
| 10 |         10 |
| 01 |          5 |
```

Test it online with [SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=418bab95e75bf5965e1f056f23428f73).